# Reusing pg-pool via module exports

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, node-pg-pool

After reading the docs: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool, I am slightly concerned about reusing the `new Pool()` method.

The docs suggests that I need to place the `new Pool()` before `exports` and `return` it like so

```
// db.js
const pool = new Pool();
module.exports = () => { return pool; }
```

This way I can reuse `Pool` until the `idleTimeoutMillis` or `client.release()`, by using `require()` from other files
Eg:

```
const connect = require('./db')
connect().query(' .... ');
```

**If this is correct**, how does it work? Does node.js caches the `new Pool()`, as it not inside `module.exports`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is effectively cached since you create it exactly once (and node caches modules) and you always refer to that same instance in your exported method.

Comment: Thanks, so that means I should always export the result only without dependencies, etc... ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, actually after testing this code, I get  `TypeError: connect.query is not a function`. It seems like the pool isn't initialized before `require()`. Do you know what's wrong? Reference: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool#a-note-on-instances

Comment: You're exporting a *function* that returns a db connection, so you'd need to do: `connect().query()`.

Comment: Thanks, and what should I do to have `connect().query()` written as `connect.query()` , apart from doing this -> `const connect = connect();`

Comment: You *could* export a function that calls `pool.connect().query(...)`, passing its arguments.

Comment: last question... I could export `Pool()` like so `module.exports = new Pool()` (as an object). So should I `return` it as a function or use it as an object? What the best practice?

Comment: I don't think there is a best practice, it's just whatever you find more convenient.

Comment: @Atartica for a friendlier API that doesn't require connecting, see [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, by creating the instance just once, you allow the node to cache it, and subsequently, you maintain a consistent reference to that identical instance within your exported method